# Strange Automapper behavior for derived object mapping

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

guys.

I have a strange behavior of Automapper when I try to map derived objects from one root.

For example:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedUser1 : User
{
    public int SomeProp1 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedUser2 : User 
{
    public int SomeProp2 { get; set; }

public class SubDerivedUser3 : DerivedUser2
{
    public int SomeProp3 { get; set; }
}
```

I use `CreateMap` like this:

```
CreateMap<User, User>()
         .ForMember(e => e.Id, f => f.Ignore())
         .IncludeAllDerived()
         .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
         {
             dest.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
         });
```

Let see the code of mapping below:

```
var testUser1 = new DerivedUser1();
var testUser2 = new SubDerivedUser3();

mapper.Map(testUser2, testUser1, testUser2.GetType(), testUser1.GetType());
```

When I try to execute this code, I have an error:

> "No coercion operator is defined between types 'DerivedUser1' and
>   'DerivedUser2'"

I thought that `IncludeAllDerived()` always check a whole derivation tree. Could someone explain to me the reason of this error?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think automapper check all tree but only type of base class. You need specify next  mapping for another class. Your class SubDerivedUser3 has no desired base class. According to docs `Inheriting base class configuration is opt-in, and you can either explicitly specify the mapping to inherit from the base type configuration with Include or in the derived type configuration with IncludeBase`

Comment: Drop `IncludeAllDerived` and use `Include/IncludeBase`. It will help you understand how things work. Also see http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I know, I read Automapper docs. Also in this docs you can see this code: `CreateMap<BaseEntity, BaseDto>().IncludeAllDerived(); CreateMap<DerivedEntity, DerivedDto>();` which allows not to map all possible inheritance manually.

Comment: @daremachine, Yes, I see, you are right. Damn, I don't want to manually set all possible mappings, because this class hierarchy is more complex now. ((((